# Return a Java Object that has 2D Array from C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a Java Object:

```
    int  numberOfROI;
    int ptrToNumberOfPointsInEachROI[];
    double ptrToROIListContaingROI[][];
}
```

I am trying to return the **JAVA OBJECT** from C++ using JNI. I am able to set both the INT and 1D array member variables. **But i am not successful in trying to set the 2D Array.**

As I have mentioned: I am able to set numberOfROI (int), and ptrToNumberOfPointsInEachROI 1D array. but failing to Set ptrToROIListContaingROI, which is a 2D array.

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {

    jclass myClass = env->FindClass("ROI_LIST_INFO");
    jobject jobj = env->AllocObject(myClass);
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(myClass, "numberOfROI", "I");
    env->SetIntField(jobj, fid, 10);  // Set Int

    jfieldID fid1 = env->GetFieldID(myClass, "ptrToNumberOfPointsInEachROI", "[I");  //Set 1D Array
    jint attribs[] = {
            66,77
        };

    //int len = SDL_arraysize(attribs);
    jintArray intArry = env->NewIntArray(2);
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(intArry, 0, 2, attribs);
    env->SetObjectField(jobj,fid1,intArry);


    jdouble attribDouble[][2] = { {66.6,77.7},{88.8,99.9}};
    jfieldID fid2 = env->GetFieldID(myClass, "ptrToROIListContaingROI", "[[D");

    jdoubleArray jrow;
    jdouble row[2];
    jobjectArray rows;

     for(int j=0;j<2;j++){

            //Traverse columns
            for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
                //Set current element of the matrix accordingly
                row[k] = attribDouble[j][k];
            }

            //Temporarily allocate a new row in JVM heap space
            //No need to unpin an array allocated with New...Array in the end
            jrow = env->NewDoubleArray(2);

            //Fill the newly allocated row
            env->SetDoubleArrayRegion(jrow,0,2,row);
            //Write the newly filled row to the appropriate row of our matrix
            //env->SetObjectArrayElement((jobjectArray)jrow, j, (jobject)row);

            env->SetObjectArrayElement(rows,j,jrow);

            printf("INNER rows[j] %d:\n",rows[j]);
        }
        //env->SetObjectField(jobj,fid2,rows);

   return jobj;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've left `rows` uninitialized. To create a new `double[][]` you need to do something like:

```
jclass double_array_class = env->FindClass("[D");
jobjectArray rows = env->NewObjectArray(2, double_array_class, NULL);
```

Also, you shouldn't try to subscript `rows` like you're doing in that `printf`. It holds (or points) to a reference to the Java array, but it is not an array itself.

Comment: It worked. But i still dont understand what the following lines are supposedly doing:
   
`
`
`
`jclass double_array_class = env->FindClass("[D");

jobjectArray rows = env->NewObjectArray(2, double_array_class, NULL);
`

Comment: The first obtains a reference to the Java `Class` for a `double[]`. The second creates an array with 2 elements, where each element is a `double[]`. Refer to [the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: Thanks a Lot. Your answer has helped in closing an issue i been scratching my head on, for a couple of days now.

Comment: HI Michael: care to help this: 
with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66657887/how-to-convert-c-datatype-double-to-jni-data-type-jdouble-xx